# Declarative Jenkinsfile CIFS share

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i have another question about the jenkins pipeline.

How can i publish the build artifacts to a windows share? In normal build jobs there is a "CIFS Publisher" post build action. But how can i use it in

```
post{
    success {
       //publish build artifacts
    }
}
```

Is there any example?

Answer (score 5):

I've succesfully managed it in this way:

```
cifsPublisher alwaysPublishFromMaster: false, continueOnError: false, failOnError: false, publishers: [[
  configName: 'NAME_OF_THE_CIFS_CONFIG', transfers: [[
    cleanRemote: false, 
    excludes: '', 
    flatten: false, 
    makeEmptyDirs: false, 
    noDefaultExcludes: false, 
    patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
    remoteDirectory: '$BUILD_NUMBER', 
    remoteDirectorySDF: false, 
    removePrefix: '', 
    sourceFiles: 'myfile']], 
  usePromotionTimestamp: false, 
  useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, 
  verbose: true
]]
```

Comment: What does alwaysPublishFromMaster: false do?  Seems like each stage in jenkinsfile pulls straight from SCM again, and not from existing artificacts/binaries.

Comment: `alwaysPublishFromMaster: false` is the default. The doc says:  *This option will cause the files to be transferred through the master before being sent to the remote server*.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the auto generate tool in Jenkins to help you.
[image]

As you can see the highlight link. Click it.
[image]

Fill all the required value that you expected.

After scroll down and click **Generate pipeline script**, you will see the syntax that you need.

[image]

Last step, copy the generated script into success clause.

Comment: I have installed sshPublisher and cifsPublisher and both don't appear in this section. So I have to look through Google to find the syntax... quite bad.